# How to update the column of the table through php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

i am new in php. I want to how i can update information to a column that is already in a database when the approve button is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
   if(isset($_POST["Button"]))
 {
   if(mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET column1=value, column2=value,... WHERE some_column=some_value"))
   {
    echo "Record Updated";
   }
  else
  {
   echo mysql_error();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass,dbc);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

$query = $mysqli->query("");// update table query
mysql_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: How can this make update to the column of the existing table ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type"submit" name="approve" value="">
include("your dbconnection.php");
if(isset($_POST["approve"]))//approve button set
    {
    UPDATE `table_name`
    SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
    WHERE some_column=some_value

     }
```

Comment: do i need to write down all the column that is in the table after WHERE or i can write a few column only

Comment: @user3458883 ,only the column which has to be updated

Comment: i understood but i am really confuse that there are lots of column in my table and i need to mention after WHERE all the columns are to be written

Comment: @user3458883 ,Yes you have to mention which column has to be updated

Comment: I know that should be mentioned i got it but do i need to mention all the other columns or i can mention only one other column ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial from W3 Schools..

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

also there are many tutorials there and best website to learn PHP for beginners.